# Gnu Radio, Radar Toolbox - angle simulator

Tags: gnuradio

I have a problem with 'Static Target Simulator' from gr-radar toolbox. Simulation of azimuth (angle) works only for few specific values.

Gr-radar is provided with tests for every module (written by author). I ran included in sources test (gr-radar/python/qa_static_target_simulator_cc.py), but with changed azimuth parameter (line 130). Tests passed with azimuth = 10 (original value), but failed with 4,9,15, 20 etc. (my example values)
(fails in line 191, self.assertAlmostEqual())

Would anyone be so kind as to confirm my suspicions? Is this simulator not working well?

Comment: Hi ppop, welcome to StackOverflow. I can't really give you an answer, and I'm afraid the GNU Radio community and the author of gr-radar aren't likely to browse by here. Why don't you write Stefan (author!) an email?

Comment: also, *"doesn't work for me"* definitely doesn't tell us **anything** about the problem you're facing, so you should maybe improve both your answer and your email with details.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller , have you ever worked with Gnu Radio?

Gr-radar have included tests (standard unit tests wrote in python). My problem is that it didn't passed included tests with changed parameters. I thought that idea of "unit tests" is known on stackoverflow. 

For example: included tests are checking if number "2" is even. Test is passed. But when i changed to number "4" test are not passed. (In my problem I'm changing azimuth of object, but it will help you understand).

I wrote an email to author more than month ago, but get no reply.

Comment: Hi @ppop, yes, I work with GNU Radio :) Hm, Stefan not replying might be because he's really absurdly busy right now. Your original question doesn't even mention the unit tests; I can't guess whatever goes wrong from your description. Why don't you just start editing your question and insert all the details that might be of interest, like *exactly* what you've tried to modify, and what then happened. "unittest fails" is not an exact statement, either -- which test? How? What did you change? You changed azimuth, but where? I know gr-radar quite well, and you're still not giving enough detail.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The question should be now improved.

Comment: In fact, now that I know what I'm looking for, it turns out that the test is broken in the current master branch. What commit are you on (`git rev-list --max-count 1 HEAD`)?

Comment: I don't have version from git. I'm using version from live CD - ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64-gnuradio-3.7.8git-snapshot-2015-0623.

That was my second guess. So, static target simulator works well, yes?

Comment: can you cd into the gr-radar directory, and execute the git command I mentioned? As far as I know, these are really just git checkouts. The fact that it's broken on current head is because something else changed its API, so it's not a sign of acute brokenness.

Comment: Is this the version number, you asked about?
3b933d9a849aa392e14846ce4da81919606f12d1

Comment: Hm, that's not in the history of the repository, as far as I can tell... I'm confused. Really, this is getting really hard to debug in StackOverflow comments for me alone; would you mind describing the problem in an email to discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org after signing up on https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.